Why does my forecast/prediction using a VAR in statsmodels quickly converge to zero?
Outline: I am using a vector autoregression (VAR) model from the statsmodel package https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/vector_ar.html#var.
My two time-series, let us call them time-series 1) ts1 and 2) ts2, are each 774 sampling points long. I train the VAR on the first 80% of the data length, and then use remaining 20% for prediciton/forecast. The optimal lag was determined using the Bayesian information criterion (BIC).
Moreover, since both time-series lacked stationarity, I first applied first-order differencing on them and subsequently also applied a linear detrending. The additional linear detrending was used because there was still a minimal linear trend left in the data after differencing.
Code:
Here is an example of my code.
from statsmodels.tsa.api import VAR
import pandas as pd

df_train = pd.DataFrame({"ts2": ts2,
                         "ts1": ts1})
len_train = round(len(df_train) * 0.8)
train = df[:len_train]

# VAR train on the first 80% train data
model = VAR(df_train)
model_fit = model.fit(bic_lag) 

# Prediction/forecast on the last 20% test data
len_test = round(len(df) * 0.2)
test =  df[len_train:]

# DataFrame to 2d numpy array
test = pd.DataFrame.to_numpy(test)

# Prediction
y_pred = model_fit.forecast(y=test, steps=len_test)

# Select first column (ts2)
y_pred = y_pred[:, 0]

# True values
y_true = var2_var[len_train:]

Problem:
Now, we can plot the predicted y_pred (in red color) and the real values y_true (in blue color), shown in the plot below. As we can see, the prediction y_pred quickly converges to zero and remains there.

Question: Here is my question as someone still new to prediction and forecasting. Why does the model simply not predict properly further than data ~20 points? What are possible reasons for the fact that the prediction converges to zero relatively quickly?
Finally, if required, I can add the two time-series here for reproducibility. I refrained from this for now because I did not want to "spam" my question with a long list of data.

Provided none finds a blatant error in your code, and your question is about correct use of a model, you might get more answers after posting in Cross-Validated or Data-Science. although, looking at tags, [statsmodel] still gets more traffic here on Stack-Overflow

This always happens when forecasting with the VAR model. VAR gives a mean for long-term forecasting, which can be computed by hand. Using a larger lag order can help if you want to forecast a bit longer.
